# TextBlock or RichTextBox is giving me trimmed text

Tags: c#, xaml, parsing, windows-phone-8, listbox

I am getting Raw text from Server API via XML parsing. i am checking that full text is going into array/list, but it gets trimmed when displayed in page inside textblock or richtextbox.

here is XAML for Listbox which contains my richtextbox:

```
         <ListBox Name="ListboxPolicy" Background="#FF5F113C" Opacity="0.93"  Foreground="#FFF5E0EC" Margin="0,137,0,0">


            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate >
                    <StackPanel>
                        <!--<TextBlock x:Name="PolicyText" TextAlignment="Justify"  Text="{Binding policyDetailsData}"  TextWrapping="Wrap" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>-->
                        <RichTextBox  x:Name="BoxPolicies" IsHitTestVisible="False" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" SizeChanged="BoxPolicies_SizeChanged" >
                            <Paragraph FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FFDABCD5">

                                <Run Text="{Binding Path=policyTitleData}" />
                            </Paragraph>
                            <Paragraph  FontSize="20" TextAlignment="Justify" >

                                <Run   Text="{Binding Path=policyDetailsData}" />
                            </Paragraph>
                            <Paragraph FontSize="20">

                                <Run Text="-----------------------------" />
                            </Paragraph>
                        </RichTextBox>


                        <!--<TextBlock x:Name="PolicyHeader"  Text="{Binding policyTitleData}"  TextWrapping="Wrap" IsHitTestVisible="False" Foreground="#FF13090E" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="22"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="PolicyText"    Text="{Binding policyDetailsData}"  TextWrapping="Wrap" IsHitTestVisible="False" FontSize="20"/>-->



                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>


        </ListBox>
```

Comment: have you tried removing the Margin="0,137,0,0"?

Comment: yes, but doesnt work :(

Answer (score 1):

Default Orientation Of **StackPanel** is Vertical and it takes height and width of child element(here RichTextBox) if you dont set Height and Width to stackpanel.

> To avoid Text Trimming you need to **Set StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" and Height and Width to RichtextBox**

```
     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <RichTextBox  x:Name="BoxPolicies" IsHitTestVisible="False" Height="400" Width="400" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <FlowDocument >
                <Paragraph FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Red">
                    <Run />
                </Paragraph>
                <Paragraph  FontSize="20" TextAlignment="Justify" >
                    <Run />
                </Paragraph>
            </FlowDocument>
        </RichTextBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

The amount of text that could be displayed in a single TextBlock is limited for performance reasons. What worked for me was splitting the text into paragraphs, putting each in a separate TextBlock and adding all to a StackPanel.

There's an implemented solution in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/09/08/creating-scrollable-textblock-for-wp7.aspx)

Comment: My data is dynamic. its coming from an API which gets xml parsed

Comment: @AtìfShabëër I do understand that. Upon receiving the text, split it into paragraphs, if you can be sure, that the text doesn't have excesivelly large paragraphs. Or try the ScrollableTextBlock in the link, which allows for a simple binding just like in your TextBock, though i'm not sure if it would look good in the places where it brakes the text.

Comment: Tried your solution. Made a custom control. but GetTextBlock() and GetMaxTextSize() in the code gives me an error : not found

Comment: @AtìfShabëër The code is not complete, attached source code link is dead, so it's only a direction to go into. Try this link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stankovski/archive/2013/08/27/yet-another-scrollable-textblock-for-windows-phone.aspx
It seems it splits text in a better way. I myself in this situation simply split the text on line breaks.